# How does Overleaf render LaTeX online?

Tags: compiling, overleaf, html

First of all, I'm sorry if this is not the appropriate  page to ask, I will delete this thread if necessary.

I want to show a compiled version of some latex document (that should be able to be modified in real time) in my website. Looking at Overleaf and ShareLaTeX, they do this by using a HTML-canvas object. How do they do so? What I'm guessing is they compile is using a normal LaTeX compiler and then convert the PDF to SVG or something like that and upload it to the website. The other option is having a parser that converts `.tex` into canvas objects, though this is much harder. Can anyone confirm which of these is the approach they are using, or if it's another?

Comment: What is your end goal?  If you're talking about the entire document being able to be modified, that will be quite difficult to implement.  If you're talking about allowing a few fields to be modified, it would probably be better to go with html/css/js.  There are also several tex -> html converters that could be useful, although you would still need to configure your server to use them appropriately.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Overleaf uses a “normal latex compiler” (they recently [upgraded to TeX Live 2018](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-upgrade-september-2019)) on the backend. That is, converting your `.tex` file into PDF (using `pdflatex` or `xelatex` or whatever) happens on Overleaf's servers. After that, the system sends the resulting PDF to your browser, where their frontend code uses [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js) to render the PDF in a HTML canvas. Some part of the Overleaf/ShareLaTeX source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf) (the original 2014 blog post was [at this link (now redirected)](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2014/02/21/sharelatex-is-now-open-source.html)).

Apart from Overleaf, as far as “I want to show a compiled version of some latex document […] in my website” goes, another option is to produce DVI (instead of PDF) on the server, and then convert to SVG using [dvisvgm](https://dvisvgm.de/).

The other possible approach is to run the compilation process in the user's browser instead. I know of two projects that aim to do this; so far both are experimental and rather slow:

- There exists [texlive.js](https://github.com/manuels/texlive.js/) (see [demo](https://manuels.github.io/texlive.js/)) and [xetex.js](https://github.com/lyze/xetex-js), which compile the TeX Live code to Javascript via Emscripten (could also compile to WebAssembly instead these days).
- There's also Jim Fowler's recent work; see demo [here](https://people.math.osu.edu/fowler.291/latex/) and [here](http://tikzjax.com/), source code [here](https://github.com/kisonecat/web2js)/[here](https://github.com/kisonecat/dvi2html)/[here](https://github.com/kisonecat/tikzjax), and [TUGboat article in Vol 40 (2019) Issue 1](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb40-1/tb124fowler-js.pdf). This compiles the WEB/Pascal code of TeX using a custom compiler into WebAssembly, then uses a custom DVI converter to render into HTML.

Comment: Hello, this is Tom from Overleaf Support Team. Thanks for this answer! I can testify that this post describes our process precisely. I would just stress that the LaTeX compilation runs on our servers, and not in the browser.

Comment: @yo' Yes realized that "backend" may not make that clear enough; have edited to clarify.

Comment: Thanks! :) ....